# setting content in medium size device - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

i'm creating a grid of two rows, first one would be the sidebar and the other one (with other two rows in his inside) is the main content:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-2 col-align-self-center sidebar" style="border-right: 5px solid #b3daff ">
      <ul>
        <li><button style="border:1px solid #9dbbe4;" class="change-button" id="change-order"  onclick="change()"  type="button">Start Moving</button></li>
        <li><button style="border:1px solid #9dbbe4;" class="change-button" onclick="stop()"  type="button">Stop Moving</button></li>
        <li><button style="border:1px solid #9dbbe4;" class="change-button"  onclick="hide()"  type="button">Hide Elements</button></li>
        <li><button style="border:1px solid #9dbbe4;" class="change-button"  onclick="hide()"  type="button">Hide Elements</button></li>
        <li><button style="border:1px solid #9dbbe4;" class="change-button"  onclick="restore()"  type="button">Restore Elements</button></li>
        <li><button style="border:1px solid #9dbbe4;" class="change-button" onclick="zoom()"  type="button">Zoom In</button></li>
        <li><button style="border:1px solid #9dbbe4;" class="change-button" onclick="resize()"  type="button">Zoom Out</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-10 main-content">
      <div class="row"> <!--first row -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
          <div class="box" style="order:1">
            <img class="meeseks" src="img/meeseks_purple.jpg" />
            <div class="button-box">
              <button style="background-color:#BA69B6;border:4px solid #BA69B6" class="button" type="button">Pick Up My Color!</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
          <div class="box" style="order:2">
            <img class="meeseks" src="img/meeseks_purple.jpg" />
            <div class="button-box">
              <button style="background-color:#BA69B6;border:4px solid #BA69B6" class="button" type="button">Pick Up My Color!</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
          <div class="box" style="order:3">
            <img class="meeseks" src="img/meeseks_purple.jpg" />
            <div class="button-box">
              <button style="background-color:#BA69B6;border:4px solid #BA69B6" class="button" type="button">Pick Up My Color!</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
          <div class="box" style="order:4">
            <img class="meeseks" src="img/meeseks_purple.jpg" />
            <div class="button-box">
              <button style="background-color:#BA69B6;border:4px solid #BA69B6" class="button" type="button">Pick Up My Color!</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="row"> <!--second row -->
        <div class="col-md-3">col</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">col</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">col</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">col</div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

working well on xs device and sm device. But in some resolution for md device (like 1024x768 ) the images dont have the correct spacing and overflow their wrapper. How can i solve?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

ok, i had forgotten the overflow property, now when i resize the page the images dont overflow they div box. The effect is not so nice, but is much better.